# How to prevent google translator, change the format of dates?

Tags: html, formatting, google-translate

I have a problem related to Google Translate.

I have the following format for dates:

DD / MM / YYYY

For example:
31/12/1999

However, when Google translate passes through my site, it changes to:

MM / DD / YYYY

12/31/1999

How could I prevent this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the code below

```
<html lang="en" class="notranslate" translate="no">
<head><meta name="google" content="notranslate" /> </head>
```

This worked for me.

;D

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="notranslate">12/31/1999</span>
```